# How to refer to a Public variable in a Form?

Tags: vba, scope

For VBA (in my case, MS Excel), the `Public` declaration is supposed to make the variable (or function) globally accessible by other functions or subroutines in that module, as well as in any other module.

This is not true, in the case of `Forms`, and I suspect also in `Sheets`, but I haven't verified the latter.

The following will not create a public, accessible variable when created in a `Form`, and will therefore crash, saying that the bYesNo and dRate variables are undefined in mModule1:

```vb
'(inside fMyForm)
Public bYesNo As Boolean`
Public dRate As Double

Private Sub SetVals()
    bYesNo = Me.cbShouldIHaveADrink.value
    dRate = CDec(Me.tbHowManyPerHour.value)
End Sub
'(Presume the textbox & checkbox are defined in the form)

'(inside mModule1)
Private Sub PrintVals()
    Debug.Print CStr(bYesNo)
    Debug.Print CStr(dRate)
End Sub
```

If you make the alteration below, it all will work:

```vb
'(inside fMyForm)

Private Sub SetVals()
    bYesNo = Me.cbShouldIHaveADrink.value
    dRate = CDec(Me.tbHowManyPerHour.value)
End Sub
'(Presume the textbox & checkbox are defined in the form)

'(inside mModule1)
Public bYesNo As Boolean
Public dRate As Double
Private Sub PrintVals()
    Debug.Print CStr(bYesNo)
    Debug.Print CStr(dRate)
End Sub
```

`mModule1` will work and, assuming that the fMyForm is always called first, then by the time the `PrintVals` routine is run, the values from the textbox and checkbox in the form will be captured.

Comment: Userform and Sheet modules are Object modules: they don't behave the same way as a regular module. You can however refer to a variable in a userform in a similar way to how you'd refer to a class property.  In your example referring to `fMyForm.bYesNo` would work fine. If you'd not declared bYesNo as Public it wouldn't be visible to code outside of the form, so when you make it Public it really is different from non-Public.

Comment: It is a known fact that if you want true public variables you need to declare them in a code module and not in the Form/Sheet code area. See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx `Public variables can be used in any procedures in the project. If a public variable is declared in a standard module or a class module, it can also be used in any projects that reference the project where the public variable is declared.`

Comment: Regarding you last comment `which are so poorly documented that a Google search in 2013 for something that has likely been around for a decade or more is so challenging to search.` Maybe you are searching using the wrong keyword? Try searching this in Google? `msdn VBA declare public variables` ;)

Comment: These absolutely are Public variables, they just do not have Global names.  Because they are part of instanced objects (the Form) they cannot have a Global name because if you made a second instance of your form, it would include a second set of public variables and then VBA would not know which one `Debug.Print bYesNo` was referring to.

Comment: As already mentioned, if you want the old style (pre-V4) `Global` behavior, you need to use modules

Comment: @Tim, thanks for the information.  Yes, you're correct that I could call it as a class property.  The problem is that this requires an instance of the form to be initialized.  In my case, without severely altering the code I'd already had, the initialization would clear the very information I was trying to get it.

For my task, I was able to resolve everything by simply declaring the public variables outside of the form module, as I'd shown above.  This was by far the simplest, best, and most robust resolution FOR MY PARTICULAR CASE.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Mike - you don't have to create an instance of the form to get at a Public variable declared in the form. Eg. if your form is called `frmTest` and has a Public variable `Blah` then you can set/get using `frmTest.Blah` without (directly) creating an instance of the form (because behind the scenes there's always a "default instance" of frmTest waiting to be referred to). However, if you create a new instance then that instance will not share the value of `Blah`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick add-on answer to the community answer, just for a heads-up:

When you instantiate your forms, you can use the form object itself, or you can create a new instance of the form object by using New and putting it in a variable.  The latter method is cleaner IMO, since this makes the usage less singleton-ish.

However, when in your userform you Call Unload(Me), *all* public members will be wiped clean.  So, if your code goes like this:

```
  Dim oForm as frmWhatever
  Set oForm = New frmWhatever
  Call oForm.Show(vbModal)
  If Not oForm.bCancelled Then  ' <- poof - bCancelled is wiped clean at this point
```

The solution I use to prevent this, and it is a nice alternative solution for the OP as well, is to capture all IO with the form (i.e. all public members) into a separate class, and use an instance of that class to communicate with the form.  So, e.g.

```
  Dim oFormResult As CWhateverResult
  Set oFormResult = New CWhateverResult
  Dim oForm as frmWhatever
  Set oForm = New frmWhatever
  Call oForm.Initialize(oFormResult)
  Call oForm.Show(vbModal)
  If Not oFormResult.bCancelled Then  ' <- safe
```

Answer (score 7):

First comment:

Userform and Sheet modules are Object modules: they don't behave the same way as a regular module. You can however refer to a variable in a userform in a similar way to how you'd refer to a class property. In your example referring to fMyForm.bYesNo would work fine. If you'd not declared bYesNo as Public it wouldn't be visible to code outside of the form, so when you make it Public it really is different from non-Public. – Tim Williams Apr 11 '13 at 21:39

is actually a correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

There are other limitations to Public within Excel VBA.
MSoft documentation in learn.microsoft.com states that public variables are global to the VBA project - it's not true.
Public variables are only global to the workbook within which they are declared, and then only across standard modules. Public variables declared within workbook code are not visible in standard modules, even though standard module sub's are - which are defined to be public.
Public variables declared in one workbook's standard modules are certainly not accessible from other workbooks in the same VBA project, contrary to the MSoft documentation.