# Passing VBA variable to Access Query Criteria

Tags: sql, vba, function, ms-access

I have a simple task giving me a lot of trouble.

What I need is to simply move a variable from my VBA macro to a function, to be able to use it in an Access Query.

ADDED: I have created a small and simple access document with a simple VBA. Download it at:
http://sharesend.com/olpy1o7d

If someone could be kind to download and see what I am doing wrong, I would really prefer it.
In the form `f_main` I need to be able to change `counter` to whatever number and hence get an updated query when the button is pressed in the main form.

It is described below, but downloading it may explain my situation easier.

EDITED:

```
Public counter as Integer

Private Sub Command_Click()

counter = 1

End Sub
```

And in a module:

```
Public Function n()
n = counter
End Function
```

In access, I have a SQL Query as:

```
SELECT t_Data.ID, n() AS Expr1 FROM t_Data;
```

Access says it can not find the function n()

If i use the function builder, i can see n(), so  i guess it is because the function n() is empty - It can not find "counter" declared in my form.

What can i do?

Comment: I've deleted my answer since the question has changed quite a bit, I would add tags for Access and VBA, and you may get more help, but I've run out of time on this end.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense in its current form. Where does `binsize` come into play here? Or the kW? How is the `SELECT` statement called? And why does it need a column with the value of the counter? How are the queries `q_PowerBinned_0x` defined?

Comment: The binsize and kW was only to explain the issue to Ian, as he asked for the application purpose. It does not matter. I just need VBA to pass variables to the Query criteria. Thats it. It is a quite large program and it would take a really long time to walk through it. So the binsize and kW are just used as examples.

Comment: Updated to be simple again.

Comment: Make sure that your function is declared in a regular `Module`, not a `Class Module` for a Form or Report.

Comment: Hi Gord, it is not a class module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help future bummers like mine, I found the error.

I named the module the same as the function, which caused the problem.

By changing the name of the module from `n` to `m_n`, and keeping the function name `n()` it worked perfectly fine.

Stupid mistake is stupid. But thank you guys who looked into my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a variable as public in a form seems to not actually make it globally public. This has annoyed me many times in Access. Move your declaration of counter to your Module code and you should see a change in operation.

There is a good discussion of this behavior in the following SO post ([Public variables are not REALLY public in VBA in Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959018/public-variables-are-not-really-public-in-vba-in-forms)).

Comment: I see your point and I tried it, but it did not work. The query still says that the function n() does not excist when i try to use it in a criteria. i get the error "Undefined function "n" in expression". I must be doing something wrong. The expression builder can see the function n() but when i try and run it, i get the error...

Comment: Hi Keven. In the question, I have added an access database with some random numbers. Could you please have a look at it? I can't find the problem and it is driving me crazy.