# modify value to public array doesn't work

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an issue to modify value of an array declared public.

So there is my code :

in the Declarations of UserForm1 I have

`Public MyArray as Variant`

in the "Private Sub UserForm_activate()" I have :

```
MyArray = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Until there it's working

---

in the UserForm3 I have :

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If UserForm1.MyArray(4) = 1 Then
    UserForm1.MyArray(0) = 1
    UserForm1.MyArray(4) = 0
ElseIf UserForm1.MyArray(0) = 1 Then
    UserForm1.MyArray(0) = 0
    UserForm1.MyArray(4) = 1
End If
End Sub
```

When I debug I see that MyArray(0) for example never change to 1

I always used public variables and that was working but not with array's

Read the array is ok but not modify the value...

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: The public myArray doesn't belong to UserForm1 so why is it called as `UserForm1.MyArray(4)` ? For that matter, how are you even using it that way? Do you have [Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) at the top of every worksheet? If not use the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor  ► Require Variable Declaration to put it there.

Comment: I declared myArray at the very top of the UserForm1.

Comment: How does that make it a member of UserForm1? What is the status I asked for on `Option Explicit` ?

Comment: @MathieuDebouvries You might want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959018/public-variables-are-not-really-public-in-vba-in-forms

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve when declaring the array private and create functions like Get/Set MyArrayValue. Then after the UserForm1 creates the UserForm3 the Parent property will be set so the UserForm3 can reach the UserForm1 functions for Get/Set MyArray. HTH

> UserForm1 - parent form

```
Option Explicit

Private m_MyArray As Variant
Private m_childForm As UserForm3

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    m_childForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set m_childForm = New UserForm3
    Set m_childForm.MyParent = Me
    m_MyArray = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
End Sub

Public Function GetMyArrayValue(index) As Variant
    GetMyArrayValue = m_MyArray(index)
End Function

Public Sub SetMyArrayValue(index, newValue)
    m_MyArray(index) = newValue
End Sub
```

> UserForm3 - child form

```
Option Explicit

Private m_parent As UserForm1

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If m_parent.GetMyArrayValue(4) = 1 Then
        m_parent.SetMyArrayValue 0, 1
        m_parent.SetMyArrayValue 4, 0
    End If
End Sub

Public Property Set MyParent(ByVal vNewValue As UserForm)
    Set m_parent = vNewValue
End Property
```